# How to delete a value from list within pandas dataframe when the value Is in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which contains two columns.

In the column "store" I have a numeric value, in the column "store_list" - a list of numerical values.

| store | store_list |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [2,4,8] |
| 4 | [2,4,8] |

I need to obtain third column which will be the result of deleting the value from "store" from the list "store_list".

| store | store_list | store_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | [2,4,8] | [4,8] |
| 4 | [2,4,8] | [2,8] |

I've tried to create functions like the following, but none of them did work.

def store_result(row):
if row['store'] in row['store_list']:
row['store_list'].remove(row['store'])

In some cases I get the error 'Float value is not iterable'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with `zip`, solution working if only lists in column `store_list`:

```
df['store_result'] = [[c for c in b if c != a] for a, b in zip(df.store, df.store_list)]
print (df)
   store store_list store_result
0      2  [2, 4, 8]       [4, 8]
1      4  [2, 4, 8]       [2, 8]
```

If order is not important and all values in lists are unique use difference of sets:

```
df['store_result'] = [list(set(b) - {a}) for a, b in zip(df.store, df.store_list)]
print (df)
   store store_list store_result
0      2  [2, 4, 8]       [8, 4]
1      4  [2, 4, 8]       [8, 2]
```

If possible missing values in `store_list` column:

```
print (df)
   store store_list
0      2  [2, 4, 8]
1      4  [2, 4, 8]
3      8        NaN

df['store_result'] = [[c for c in b if c != a] 
                      if isinstance(b, list) else [] 
                      for a, b in zip(df.store, df.store_list)]
print (df)
   store store_list store_result
0      2  [2, 4, 8]       [4, 8]
1      4  [2, 4, 8]       [2, 8]
3      8        NaN           []
```

Comment: In first two methods I did get the error 'TypeError: 'Float value is not iterable', but the last one worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!!